# Get servlet init params in servlet context listener

Tags: servlets, servletcontextlistener, init-parameters

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>config</listener-class>
</listener> 
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>text</param-name>
    <param-value>HelloWorld1</param-value>
</init-param>
```

```
public class config implements ServletContextListener {



@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
    String text1 = servletContext.getInitParameter("text");
```

In method  `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)` , If There would be two servlets , for example , Let's say name of the second  servlet be `Servlet2` and it  let's  say  has also has `init - param` called `text` with value `HelloWorld2` .

How does `listener`   know to take `ProcessReg` servlet ?

How to get `param` from `Servlet2` ??

Answer (score 7):

You need to distinguish between servlet initialization parameters and context initialization parameters.

Context initialization parameters are:

- context-wide;
- declared in `<context-param>` elements directly under the `<web-app>` root;
- typically accessed using the `ServletContext.getInitParameter()` method, e.g. from inside a listener's `contextInitialized()` method.

Servlet initialization parameters are:

- servlet-specific;
- declared in `<init-param>` elements inside a `<servlet>` element;
- typically accessed using the `ServletConfig.getInitParameter()` method, e.g. from inside the servlet's `init()` method.